# Python - got an unexpected keyword argument 'scope'

Tags: python

I am trying to run the `1.0-lunarlander-sim.ipynb` file from the [Deep Assist GitHub repo](https://github.com/rddy/deepassist). But I keep getting an error: `got an unexpected keyword argument 'scope'`.

```
    raw_full_pilot_policy, full_pilot_reward_data = deepq.learn(
  env,
  q_func=full_pilot_q_func,
  max_timesteps=max_timesteps,
  scope=full_pilot_scope,
  **pilot_dqn_learn_kwargs
)
```

Comment: At a guess, you'll probably need to look at the Traceback and the actual function signature for `deepq.learn()` to figure out what's wrong. You may also want to consider filing a bug report with the original author.

Answer (score 1):

(without knowing deepq), by looking in it's code you can see that scope is not a valid keyword argument for the learn function.
see here:
https://github.com/openai/baselines/blob/master/baselines/deepq/deepq.py#L95

seems that it was removed in that commit, maybe install that version of openai/baselines

https://github.com/openai/baselines/blob/8c2aea2addc9f3ba36d4a0c937e6a2d09830afc7/baselines/deepq/deepq.py